# CSS centering background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, sass

I' m building a project whit a background image, but I can't completely center the image like in this

### My goal is

[image]

### What I managed to do is

[image]

as you can see the image is not completely vertically centered and if I resize the screen the pencil tends to disappear.

[Here](https://ibb.co/28L4CHT) is the image in question.
[image]

Here the CSS code:

```css
    .app {
        height: 100%;
        background: url('./background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

I thank anyone who can help me.

```css
.app {
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="app">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is actually centered, but you want that the background will be smaller right?

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas exactly

Comment: can you send the link of the image? you can use a photo-hosting service something like `Imgur` that is amazing because you don't need a account and is trusted source

Comment: from that I know you can use `background-size: contain` (this make a border if something will overflow) or manually with a custom size first writing the width you want for the background then the height (this is not the best because the image tends to stretch) `background-size: 100vw 100vh;`

Comment: I tried but still nothing

Comment: This already centers the image, so please update your title and post to summarize/explain what you _actually_ need. And remember to use proper image markup for images. Add a `!` in front of your markup links so that the images actually show up in your post (and then remember to change the text around it so that things make sense). But: remember to _not_ use images for code, or code results. SO already has a runnable snippet, use that to show off what you need.

Comment: @SaverioRandazzo try using  `background-position-y` this is like translateY but for background, in my PC a value like `-10em` is fine :)   `background-position-y: -10em;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## try using `background-position-y` property

actually your background is centered, but the pen in the picture is not centered

[image]

#### add some code

so you can decrease the number in the `background-position-y` something like `-10em` looks good in my computer

position-y is like translateY but for background (is for moving the background vertically)

#### or (with less code)

or for good results use PHOTOSHOP and crop the space on top, to make the image centered, then put it in HTML

*I know is not the best, but if you want less code* ¯_(ツ)_/¯
and responsive

```css
.app {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/pWsFM5S/background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position-y: -10em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="app">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I set `background-position-y` to `60%` and now the pencil is centered and responsive

Comment: appreciate  I help you! using `%` is a genius trick!, because this is really Responsive